# Select record from database where search term has an apostrophe

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have the following query that returns results for a specific customer:

```
        $enviroFigures = $dm->createQuery("
            SELECT efu.wasteType, efu.ewcCode, SUM(efu.totalUom) AS totalTonne, SUM(efu.co2Saving) AS totalCO2
            FROM CoreBundle:EnviroFiguresUpload efu
            WHERE efu.customerSite = :site
            AND efu.completionDate BETWEEN :start AND :end
            AND efu.completionDate != :blank
            AND efu.totalUom != :blank
            GROUP BY efu.wasteType
            ORDER BY efu.completionDate DESC"
        )->setParameters(array(
            "site" => $selectTerm,
            "start" => $ds,
            "end" => $de,
            "blank" => ""
        ));

        $enviFig = $enviroFigures->getResult();
```

The `$selectTerm` can have an apostrophe contained within it (such as `TGI Friday's`), but this causes an errory within PHP as the apostrophe closes the query. How can I avoid this? I can't remove the apostrophe from the variable.

**EDIT**
This is the error entry in the log.

> [2015-01-11 11:31:42] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: "An exception occurred while executing
>   'SELECT SUM(total_uom) AS totalTonne, waste_hierarchy, completion_date
>   FROM enviro_figures_upload WHERE customer_reference = 'TGI Friday's
>   Glasgow' AND completion_date BETWEEN '2014-01-11' AND '1970-01-01' AND
>   completion_date != '' AND waste_hierarchy != '' GROUP BY
>   waste_hierarchy, DATE_FORMAT(completion_date, '%m-%Y') DESC ORDER BY
>   YEAR(completion_date) ASC, MONTH(completion_date) ASC, waste_hierarchy
>   ASC': SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Glasgow' AND
>   completion_date BETWEEN '2014-01-11' AND '1970-01-01' AND complet' at
>   line 1" at
>   /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php line
>   91 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: An exception
>   occurred while executing 'SELECT SUM(total_uom) AS totalTonne,
>   waste_hierarchy, completion_date FROM enviro_figures_upload WHERE
>   customer_reference = 'TGI Friday's Glasgow' AND completion_date
>   BETWEEN '2014-01-11' AND '1970-01-01' AND completion_date != '' AND
>   waste_hierarchy != '' GROUP BY waste_hierarchy,
>   DATE_FORMAT(completion_date, '%m-%Y') DESC ORDER BY
>   YEAR(completion_date) ASC, MONTH(completion_date) ASC, waste_hierarchy
>   ASC':\n\nSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Glasgow'
>   AND completion_date BETWEEN '2014-01-11' AND '1970-01-01' AND complet'
>   at line 1 at
>   /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:91,
>   PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 's Glasgow' AND completion_date BETWEEN '2014-01-11' AND
>   '1970-01-01' AND complet' at line 1 at
>   /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php:165)"}

Comment: random suggestions.. addslashes() ??

Comment: Can you show the error and the SQL statement generated? Since you're using query parameters, there shouldn't be any need to escape the data.

Comment: Updated the answer with the error.